# How to take a screenshot in selenium AWS Lambda using Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, screenshot

I am writing scripts in Selenium Java to run my tests on AWS Lambda. However I am not able to find the way to be directly download those image to either to local system or to upload them in s3.
I'm using selenium with headless chrome.

I need to take a screenshot of the following code and upload it in s3 or local file on aws lambda:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Submit Your Code']")).click();
    System.out.println("Code submitted successfully");
    WebElement correct_sol=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='tdpostoutout']/span[contains(text(),'Submitted Solution is Correct!')]"));
    
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(correct_sol));
```

How do I do that?? Any suggestions please.

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible to run selenium web driver in Lambda, you can submit only an independent jar there, I would recommend using EC2 instance instead

Comment: How would we take a screenshot using the same? My main objective is that. Can you share some tutorials or links if possible?